# offset of specific row between selected rows

Tags: php, mysql

i'm writnig a very small forum for my website .. i really didn't want to use vb and other forum systems .

so

```
topics ( title , id )
posts  ( text , id , topic_id )
```

there is a page that shows all the entry(posts) of given user

in this page for each user post , i show name of the topic and a short summary of that post

here is the problem

when i click on the topic name .. i don't want to go to the first page of topic .
i want the exact page that contains that specific post .

so i gont the post id (lets say 666 )
i can get the topic information using that (lets say title : `topic A` )

so i can get total count of the posts in `topic A`

lets say

```
$total_posts_intopic = 250 ;
$per_page            = 15 ;
```

all i need now is the offset of `post #666` to figure out the page number

so how can i get the offset of post `#666` between `topic A` posts ?

or is there any easier way to do this ?

note : post no 666 means it's 666 post overall in all of the topics not in `topic A`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/133ab/5/0) for a full demonstration.

The query I used (adapted to your example) is below. The idea is that you fill in the `topic_id` (where I currently have `topic_id = 1`) and the post's `id` (where I currently have `id = 666`). The result will be a number indicating the position of the given post in the given topic.

To determine the page number, you could use:

```
$pageNumber = floor(($queryResult - 1) / $postsPerPage);
```

The query:

```
SELECT
  currentCount
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      id,
      @counter := @counter + 1 AS currentCount
    FROM
      posts,
      (SELECT @counter := 0) AS countTable
     WHERE
       topic_id = 1
  ) AS associatedCountTable
WHERE
  id = 666;
```

The query works as follows:

- The posts table is cross joined with a counter variable. This works because the variable is set to `0` when MySQL 'creates' `countTable` (when it looks at the `FROM` clause) and that variable is incremented by 1 each time a row is selected (because the `SELECT` clause is 'executed' for each result row).
- Because the `WHERE` clause (selecting the correct topic) is 'executed' *before* the `SELECT` clause, only the rows in the topic you're interested in get a counter increase.
- The result of the previous steps is a new table `associatedCountTable` with a row for each post in the selected topic. Each row has the post's `id` in the first column and a simply incrementing counter in the second column named `currentCount`.
- The final `WHERE` clause takes the above table and selects the counter column for the row with the `id` of the post you're interested in (`666` in your example).